# Take the background-running command back to terminal in Linux

Tags: linux

In Linux we can use & to make the command run in background. But how can I get it back? For example: I run yum install xxx in background and I cannot see and print information. While yum prompt a choice to install it or not. So how can I input my "yes/no" choice when yum is running background? (I notice than prompt choice show in terminal but I can input nothing.)

Answer (score 2):

When you put a task on background you create a job. To view the jobs just use:

```
jobs -l
```

Then to return a job to foreground use:

```
fg <job_number>
```

The `job_number` is not the PID, it's the number in the job list.

To get a non stop yum installation accepting the values use the `-y` flag.

```
yum -y install <package>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `-y` argument like

```
yum -y install xxxx
```

## Edit

Just thought you might want this in some other situation with program that doesn't support -y. Then try:

```
yes | yum install xxxx
```

Also this topic should be in Unix questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use -y argument like

yum -y install xxxx

Comment: Just thought you might want this in some other situation with program that doesn't support -y. Then try:

yes | yum install xxxx
Also this topic should be in Unix questions.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged 'linux', I'll assume you are using bash and that piping the output of `yes` or `-y` are not acceptable answers.  When you execute the command in the background, `bash` will have printed a line of the form:

```
[1] NNNN
```

where NNNN is the pid of the new process and the number in brackets is the job number.  To bring the job to the foreground, type: `fg %1`  (`1` is common, but if you have other jobs running it may be 2 or 3: use the value given when you spawned the process.)

Answer (score 0):

In the same shell, use the `fg` command to reattach to a job. Use `jobs` to list them. If you sleep a job with `Ctrl-z`, use `bg` to run it in the background. `fg` and `bg` take a job number as argument:

```
$ sleep 1231 &
[1] ..pid..
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 1231 &
$ fg 1
```